# Check if an id is in another model's field, and get the connected values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Given these two models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class dateEvent(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How can I filter only the venues that appear in a `dateEvent`? And how can I get the `Event` details linked to a specific venue?

Right now I attempted this, which returns `noniterable` and `non exists` error:

```
venues = list(Venue.objects.filter(dateevent__venue.icontains=id).values('venue_name', 'dateevent__event.id')
```

Comment: Appear in *any* `dateEvent` or one with a specific primary key?

Comment: Appear in any `dateEvent`. I want to differentiate between venues that appear on `dateEvent`, and get the `Event` details in that case, and the ones that don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Venue.objects.filter(dateevent__isnull=False).prefetch_related('dateevent_set').distinct()
```

the [**`.distinct()`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
prevents returning the same `Venue` multiple times.

For the `Venues`s you can access the `.dateevent_set.all()` to retrieve all the related `dateEvent`s.

Since the `dateEvent` acts as a many-to-many relation, you can span one over this model with:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class dateEvent(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(
        Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    events = models.ManyToManyField(
        Event, through='dateEvent', realted_name='venues'
    )
```

then fetching the `Event`s is even simpler:

```
qs = Venue.objects.filter(dateevent__isnull=False).prefetch_related(
    'events'
).distinct()
```

you then enumerate over the `.events.all()` of the `Venue`, so:

```
for venue in qs:
    print(venue.venue_name)
    for event in venue.events.all():
        print(f' - {event.title}')
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. How do I get the details od the related `event` though? `.values('dateevent_set__event.title'`?

Comment: See my question above 'And how can I get the Event details linked to a specific venue?'. Thank you.

Comment: @HBMCS: please *don't* use `.values()`, you can easily fetch the values by spanning a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I need a JSON serializable list, as this is in my view and I need a list, which I'll then use in my JS for a map. If I leave the `values` out I get an error.

Comment: @HBMCS: in that case you probably best use a (`Model`)`Serializer`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ this can also serialize bi-directional. Using `.values()` erodes the model layer.